# How to handle the multiple user invitations at same time in BLE in swift4?

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have implemented 1-1 chat using BLE with Swift latest version. The chat scenario is one user sends an invitation to another user. If the user accepts that request then chat get started. But the issue is when two or more users send a chat invitation parallelly and I am not able to differentiate the users. It gets automatically connected with a random user. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed with this user differentiation?

Comment: You added both Swift and Objective-C tags. Which one is it?

Comment: @wvteijlingen I am using the swift's latest version.